# Replacing a terraform deployed lambda in place with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

I've got a requirement to move from our existing terraform/gocd deployment structure for our lambdas to using codepipeline and cloudformation.

The main obstacle I've hit is cloudformation can't deploy a lambda with an existing name meaning I currently need to delete the existing lambda, for our test environment and lesser used lambdas not a huge problem but there are a few critical ones I'd rather have a cleaner way of moving across, is there a way to replace it in place?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/ !? Generally Cloudformation is REALLY bad at moving, refactoring, importing resources. That is something that should have been clear before deciding to move to CF. Note that the usage of CodePipeline is no argument for CF, you can easily run terraform in CodePipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) existing resources to CloudFormation. Please note that not all resources can be imported. The list of supported ones is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).

In terms of lambda, the following resources can be imported:

- AWS::Lambda::Alias
- AWS::Lambda::CodeSigningConfig
- AWS::Lambda::Function
- AWS::Lambda::Version

However, importing procedure is not that straightforward. For it to work you already need to have proper templates which **match the existing resources**.

Thus its better to do some practice runs on **test functions** and other resources to get familiar with the process and its requirements, before you attempt using production functions. Also, you can consider using [former2](https://former2.com/) to help you with generation of these initial templates from existing lambda as a starting point.